# creating facebook hash key for android

Tags: java, android, openssl, keytool

I followed Steps to create Hash Key.

1. Downloaded openssl
2. Unzipped and copied all the files in the bin folder including openssl.exe
3. Pasted all the files  copied from Openssl’s bin folder to the Jdk bin folder.
4. Then i used following command on openssl.exe terminal window

   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore C:\Users\Joelle.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e

but it is throwing following error

```
openssl error :'keytool is invalid command'
```

Please guide me ...

thanx

Comment: you have to set your jre->bin file to your system variable path.. then you can call keytool comand from everywhere..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keytool is usually found in JRE bin folder in my case it is present in

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin

So you should write

> cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin

then

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   C:\Users\Joelle.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary |
>   openssl enc -a -e

There is nice tool present

try to generate Key Hash with this tool http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/download/keyhash.zip

Comment: so using this method will work for debugging but when deploying the app I should replace the debug.keystore line with my app release keystore to actually work in production?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Joelle.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just writing keytool, you must specify full path of it, i.e.
In my case the path is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\keytool.exe
```